# Main Class Not Found

Tags: java

I am to connect to a MySQL database from a Java application to store images taken from a scanned form. When I run the program I get a `Could not find or load main class` error.

I have tried setting the classpath but still get the same error: `Could not find or load main class`. By the way, another java file I created in the directory compiles. When I try to set the classpath I also get the same error. Here is the (EDITED)code:

```
java -cp "C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Desktop\ttt_manual_yyy\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin" ImageUploader C:\Documents and Settings\yyy\Desktop\IMAGES localhost uuu nnn
```

Where localhost is database address,uuu is username,nnn is password

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not even specifying a class, and you need to put your classpath in quotes as it's got spaces. So it should be something like:

```
java -classpath "C:\Documents and Settings\...\ImageUpload" foo.ImageUploader
```

where `foo.ImageUploader` is the fully-qualified name of the class containing the `main` method.

Comment: Ok...i modified that a bit...but still throwing up errors....so i have edited my question to include the full code